# running a for loop to make graphs using out function

Tags: r, loops, graph, ggplot2, out

I am trying to run a loop that prints out scatter plots with ggplot2. Here is the scenario:

I have a data frame with 405,000 rows. Each row refers to a point on a scatter plot (x-value, y-value), and is also associated with a particular patient. There are numerous rows per patient.

In order to separate out data for each patient, I use the following:

```
out <- split(df, f = df$patientID)
```

Then, I can create a data frame for each patient as follows:

```
df_patientID <- out[[“patientID”]]
```

Then, I can make a scatter plot for each of these individual patient data frames:

```
pl <- ggplot(df_patientID, aes(x = df_patientID$xval, y = df_patientID$yval))
pl+geom_point(color=“red)
```

This has worked for me, but since there are 472 patients, I’d like to do a loop so I can get a scatter plot for each patient. I created a vector with all the patient ID’s ("patientIDs") and tried this:

```
`For (i in patientIDs){
j <- out[[“i”]]
pl <- ggplot(j, aes(x = df_i$xval, y=df_i$yval))
pl + geom_point(color=“red”)
```

But that only prints out a value "j" that is NULL. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of all the extra coding to create separate data frames for each patient, you can just subset the data frame by `patientID` or split the data frame by `patientID` when you create the plots. Also, you shouldn't repeat the data frame name inside `aes`. You provide the data frame as the first argument to `ggplot`. Inside `aes` you should just use column names.

Instead of a loop, you might find it easier to create a list containing all the plots, which you can then print, save, etc.

```
library(ggplot2)

plot.list = lapply(split(df, df$patientID), function(dat) {
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + 
    geom_point(color="red") +
    facet_wrap(~ patientID)
})
```

Each element of `plot.list` is a plot for one `patientID`, and the name of each list element is the value of `patientID` for that plot. For example, after you run the code above, if you want to see the plot for `patientID` 548, type `plot.list[["548"]]`. You can also save the plots to a file, lay out multiple plots on a page, etc.

To print each plot in a loop, you could do this:

```
for (i in unique(df$patientID)) {
  pl = ggplot(df[df$patientID==i, ], aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + 
    geom_point(color="red") +
    facet_wrap(~ patientID)
  print(pl)
}
```

Or you could create a list of plots for later printing, saving, etc. like this:

```
pl = list()
for (i in unique(df$patientID)) {
  pl[[i]] = ggplot(df[df$patientID==i, ], aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + 
    geom_point(color="red") +
    facet_wrap(~ patientID)
}
```

Comment: This is really great! Thank you so very much. 

Is there a way to directly save all the plots to a folder? or in one pdf file? I tried

Comment: I tried the following but did not work:

  MyPDFPath = "/Users/akalbasi/Dropbox/Coding/NIH GDC Data/Melanoma/VAF Plots/allplots.pdf"
  pdf(file=MyPDFPath)
  for (i in unique(df_MAF$Tumor_Sample_Barcode2)) {
   pl = ggplot(df_MAF[df_MAF$Tumor_Sample_Barcode2==i, ], aes(x = t_depth, y = t_alt_count)) + 
    geom_point(color="red") +
    facet_wrap(~ Tumor_Sample_Barcode2)
     }
    dev.off()
RStudioGD 
        2

Comment: nevermind, I fogt it!

'code' MyPDFPath = "/Users/akalbasi/Dropbox/Coding/NIH GDC Data/Melanoma/VAF Plots/allplots.pdf"
pdf(file=MyPDFPath)
for (i in unique(df_MAF$Tumor_Sample_Barcode2)) {
  pl = ggplot(df_MAF[df_MAF$Tumor_Sample_Barcode2==i, ], aes(x = t_depth, y = t_alt_count)) + 
    geom_point(color="red") +
    facet_wrap(~ Tumor_Sample_Barcode2)
  print(pl)
}
dev.off()